# Substitution that results in upper and lower bounds of the same value

Tags: calculus

I'm looking at this integral which has a logarithm, and it's completely obvious I should use substitution to make the integral easier... then the bounds become equivalent. I honestly have never seen this happen, but it feels like I'm doing something that is forbidden - maybe even illegal.

Here's the substitution and the original bounds: $u=3+2\cos{\theta}$ over the interval $[-\pi ,\pi]$. Then our new region of integration will be $[1,1]$. This certainly cannot be correct. How do I work around this little dilemma?

Comment: ...what's the integral?

Comment: @DMcMor Not obviously zero. I'm interested only in this problem of substitutions which yield equivalent bounds. Certainly there is a way to work around this and still use the substitution?

Comment: Your limits are wrong. Don't use $\theta$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Comment: @Andrei You can integrate over $-\pi$ to $\pi$. You see these bounds in polar coordinates all the time actually. I think my favorite is deriving the area/circumference of a circle.

Comment: What is the original integral? What is the change of variable you are attempting? Are we supposed to guess, or just answer in the absence of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right, it's illegal. To use the substitution you have to check that the new function is a bijection between the two regions os integration, and $f(\theta)=3+2\cos(\theta)$ is not injective in $[-\pi,\pi]$. You may have to consider to change the domain from $[-\pi,\pi]$ to another interval.

Comment: Hmm, you'd think I would have heard this in my first calculus course... I guess it just doesn't come up often.

Comment: “Illegal”. Would that be federal, state, local law, international law, or some other corpus of laws that will sic the cops on him if he attempts a substitution we do not know on an integral we do not know?

Comment: Yeah, no, you do not need to check that you have a bijection. For example, with $\int_{-1}^2 2\cos(x^2)x\,dx$, the substitution $u=x^2$ is perfectly valid, even though this does not provide a bijection between $[-1,1]$ and $[1,4]$. What you need if you have $\int_a^b f(g(x))g’(x)\,dx$ and you want to do $u=g(x)$, is for $g’(x)$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$, and  for $f$ to be continuous on the interval $g([a,b])$.

Comment: Yes, the law of change of variable. The Riemman corps could be at his door in any minute if he doesn't correct it.

Comment: Well, your “law” was passed by a legislature that didn’t know what it was doing. Your claim is false.

Comment: If you don’t have a bijection but $f$ is continuous on the range of $g$, then it doesn’t matter; the parts of the integral that would get “overwritten” cancel out. In the example I give, as $x$ ranges from $-1$ to $0$, the value of $x^2$ goes from $1$ to $0$; then as it ranges from $0$ to $1$, it goes from $0$ to $1$. The two evaluations of $\cos(u)$, from $1$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $1$, cancel each other; which is exactly what happens to $2\cos(x^2)x$ on $[-1,1]$. That’s why the change of variable I give is valid and gives the right answer, despite your assertion that it cannot be done.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, so if my integrand contains $u(x)*u'(x)$ and the bounds become equal, does that just mean that it is even or odd over the interval?

Comment: @Algebraic: Until you tell me what your integral is, I’m not going to answer. I have no idea what you did, so I cannot comment. I also cannot understand why you insist on not just telling us what your integral is, over, and over, and over again.

Comment: As far as I know if you want to use a change of variable in an integral $g:A\rightarrow B$ it has to be a difeomorphism between A and B. Maybe there are exceptions but I think tha is the general rule.

Comment: @Navareño: No, you don’t need it to be a difeomorphism for the change of variable in a Riemann integral on the real line. You just need $g’(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f(x)$ continuous on $g([a,b])$. *As I already stated*.

Comment: @Navareño: Some sources: [one](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1338515231), [two](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/34/tmn34p25-28.pdf), and [three](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614765). In fact, you just need $u’(x)$ to be integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f$ to be integrable on $u([a,b])$. But continuity will suffice.